# Difference between seq_search([ann1, ann2]) and ann1 :: ann2?

Tags: search, heuristics, constraint-programming, minizinc

What is the difference between these two methods to do the search in Minizinc?

First one:

```
solve :: seq_search([ann1, ann2]) satisfy;
```

Second one:

```
solve :: ann1 :: ann2 satisfy;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The big difference is that using seperate annotations does not guarantee an order.

Using `:: ann1 :: ann2` might first use the `ann2` or `ann1`, the order might not even be the same in the produced FlatZinc being send the the solver.

`:: seq_search([ann1, ann2])` does guarantee the order to be first `ann1` and then `ann2`.